# INNER JOIN me da error al consultar una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una consulta compuesta de dos INNER JOIN para recuperar información de 3 tablas diferentes, el problema es que me cuando coloco la clausula ON y coloco lo siguiente **egresos.cuenta = 15** me devuelve el siguiente error:

> La columna 'egresos_test.cuenta' en on clause es desconocida

Esta es mi consulta completa:

```
> SELECT cuentas.no_cuenta, sum(saldo) saldo from
> bank_log INNER JOIN cuentas ON
> cuentas.id_cuenta = 15 INNER JOIN (SELECT sum(cantidad)
> egresosTotal FROM egresos WHERE cuenta = 15) AS egresosTotal ON
> egresos.cuenta = 15 WHERE bank_log.no_cuenta = 15 ORDER BY
> bank_log.id_registro DESC LIMIT 1
```

No entiendo por que no encuentra la clomuna cuenta en el segundo INNER JOIN donde sumo la cantidad, si le estoy colocando egreso.cuenta.

**Actualización:**

He intentando haciendo uso de esta solución:

```
SELECT cuentas.no_cuenta, sum(saldo) saldo 
  from bank_log 
       INNER JOIN cuentas ON cuentas.id_cuenta = 15 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT sum(cantidad) egresosTotal 
                     FROM egresos 
                    WHERE cuenta = 15) AS egresosTotal 
 WHERE bank_log.no_cuenta = 15 
 ORDER BY bank_log.id_registro DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Pero el problema ahora es que al ejecutar la consulta no imprime el resultado de egresosTotal, unicamente me imprime dos columnas de 3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: egresos_test no existe en el query que mostras, o sea que el error no es de esa query.

Comment: Dime, donde está la tabla o alias `egresos`? si te refieres a la que está dentro del `SELECT sum(cantidad) ` entonces está mal porque  esa tabla no está al alcance fuera de ese SELECT. Aparte que ese SELECT lo has nombrado como `egresosTotal`. Esa condición debería ser un WHERE del SELECT sum y ya la tienes por lo tanto esa  condición esta demas. Raro que quieras hacer un join de una tabla con   el resultado que devuelve un escalar. Quizá te falte la cuenta y group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, no tienes bien definido el tema de la *visibilidad* de los identificadores a la hora de utilizar subconsultas.

Cuando escribes una subconsulta, dentro de un par de paréntesis, `(select columna1, columna2 from tabla1 iner join tabla2 on x = y)`, las tablas y alias que utilizas dentro de la subconsulta solamente son conocidos en ella misma (dentro de los paréntesis), pero no fuera de ella. Fuera de ella, solamente serán conocidos los nombres o alias de las columnas que devuelve la subconsulta, y podrán calificarse con el alias que le pones a esta misma, pero no con los alias internos, que son desconocidos a este nivel.

Ese es el caso cuando haces un `select from (select from... ) miAlias`, como en el ejemplo que pones.

Además, dado que la subconsulta no devuelve una columna llamada `cuenta`, tampoco podrías simplemente cambiar el alias de la condición, pues no hay columna con la cual comparar.

Hay varias soluciones:

- Cmabiar el `inner join` por un `cross join`:

```
SELECT cuentas.no_cuenta, sum(saldo) saldo 
  from bank_log 
       INNER JOIN cuentas ON cuentas.id_cuenta = 15 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT sum(cantidad) egresosTotal 
                     FROM egresos 
                    WHERE cuenta = 15) AS egresosTotal 
 WHERE bank_log.no_cuenta = 15 
 ORDER BY bank_log.id_registro DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Puedes incluir la columna en el resultado de la subconsulta, y mantener el `inner join`:

```
SELECT cuentas.no_cuenta, sum(saldo) saldo 
  from bank_log 
       INNER JOIN cuentas ON cuentas.id_cuenta = 15 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT cuenta, sum(cantidad) egresosTotal 
                     FROM egresos 
                    WHERE cuenta = 15
                    group by cuenta) AS egresosTotal on egresosTotal.Cuenta = bank_log.Cuenta
 WHERE bank_log.no_cuenta = 15 
 ORDER BY bank_log.id_registro DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Dicho esto, tu consulta tiene demasiadas referencias a la constante `15`. Cada vez que quieras consultar una cuenta diferente, tendrás que cambiar ese valor en muchos lugares. Puedes escribir la misma consulta haciendo referencia entre las columnas que relacionan las tablas en los joins, y colocar la constante solamente en la cláusula `where`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT cuentas.no_cuenta, sum(saldo) saldo 
  from bank_log 
       INNER JOIN cuentas ON cuentas.id_cuenta = bank_log.no_cuenta
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT sum(cantidad) egresosTotal 
                     FROM egresos 
                    WHERE egresos.cuenta = bank_log.no_cuenta) AS egresosTotal 
 WHERE bank_log.no_cuenta = 15 
 ORDER BY bank_log.id_registro DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Como ves, ahora el número 15 solo aparece una vez, y la consulta te sigue devolviendo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Hola jachguate, estuve revisando y probando las consultas que me hiciste favor de dejar, use la primera que propusiste que es donde usar un cross join y si funciona pero no me imprime la suma de egresosTotal, unicamente me imprime dos columnas y deben ser tres, modifico mi pregunta para agregar las imagenes del resultado

Comment: Para comenzar, tu pregunta no incluía nada sobre incluir una nueva columna. Dado que ya está resuelto el problema original, considero poco cortés cambiar la pregunta a estas alturas. Por otro lado, no se trata de que yo escriba la consulta por te, tenías una dificultad, yo he explicado con detalle cuál era tu problema con esa dificultad, lo que te  permite avanzar, si comprendes esa explicación, ya incluir esa columna, es algo que te toca hacer a ti.

Comment: Si, tienes razon, de echo lo acabo de lograr, estaba haciendo pruebas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya entendi bien como usar los CROSS y los INNER